# Is WordPress ignoring segments of Permalink?

Tags: wordpress, rename, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I discovered a strange behaviour of WordPress in the usage of permalinks. On my local machine set the permalinkstructure to:

`/%test%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`
The first part, "test" is a custom taxonomy.

This results in the following working linkstructure.
http://localhost:8080/reisbowl/2021/06/22/c/

But also, when use the url,which does not exist, the link is working and showing me the correct post "c".
http://localhost:8080/hamburger/2021/06/22/c/

**How is that? Is WordPress ignoring the custom taxonomy segment in the permalink or everything but the title?**

The question poped up because i have to rename the "reisbowl" tag (just an example) to something else and secure the redirection to the new url. But it seems that this is not any issue.

**But why? I just want to understand that.**

Comment: Rewriting in WordPress can be very strange, I recommend testing the rewrite rules with this plugin [Debug Bar Rewrite Rules](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-rewrite-rules/) it allows you to test why it matched a URL

Comment: WordPress generally works from the endpoint URL backwards. It will match the title (slug) first and then work backwards - in your case - the day, month, year and then the tag/cat/taxonomy term. To be safe, you can add a 301 redirect, but the way WP saves data in the database, you should be fine. Issues arise when you have an end slug that is the same as another post/media/page object.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. That plugin is helpfull to understand that, and how, the link-thing is working on WordPress and thank you for your explanation.